# Firefox Delaying jQuery Document.Ready Using Faye

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, node.js

I'm using faye (for node.JS) which seems to be using a never ending xmlhttprequest to get "live" data.

I have a page that (on jquery's document ready function) loads a page 
via ajax. When clicking a link within the loaded page, it loads 
another page which also contains an ajax call via the document.ready function.

When faye is running in firefox, it seems to be loading endlessly from 
the server. This seems to be throwing off jquery's document .ready 
function. It typically won't execute the code loaded from ajax for at 
least 10-30 seconds. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: This question is pretty hard to understand without some examples of code in use.

Comment: I get what you're trying to ask. Basically, you need an ajax call to fire after the DOM is READY, but the DOM is never ready because Faye is delaying it and therby your ajax call can never be timed properly. I have the very same exact problem and Im still scouting around for a solution. Let me know if you have any solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

I isolated the issue - FireFox doesn't have websockets out of the box and when it relies on an open JSONP or XMLHttp request, all other ajax queries will be slowed down (by 10-20 seconds). You get around this by putting your script into an iframe and have it fire off a function.

Here is the full explanation: http://groups.google.com/group/faye-users/browse_thread/thread/f93c5e1d1048c89e

Answer (score 1):

user800927, check out this thread in google groups for faye:
http://groups.google.com/group/faye-users/browse_thread/thread/f93c5e1d1048c89e

they explain that you need to put faye in an iframe and then execute the code via the parent window. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider switching to [socket.io](http://socket.io) unless there is something you really need from faye. Alternatively, stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions! Make sure to report back with your findings.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :) I isolated the issue a month ago or so, just forgot to post the answer until you reminded me!